# City names are not translated in Stack Overflow Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, localization

Go to [Stack Overflow Careers](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/) and select French at the bottom of the page.

Scroll back up to the top of the page and check the city names. London should be Londres in French.

[image: Londres]

Go to [Stack Overflow Careers](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/) and select German at the bottom of the page.

Scroll back up to the top of the page and check the city names again. Munich should be München in German.

[image: Munchen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good news! "Munich" is now "München" (if you're on the German site)!

[image]

But wait, there's more: "London" is now "Londres" (if you're on the French site)!

[image]

And it get's better: we might open-source the highly sophisticated city name geo-localization engine we've developed and deployed just for this bug! Here's a preview:

[image]

Happy Friday!