# London still not translated to Londres everywhere in French Stack Overflow Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, localization

City names are now translated per [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251833/city-names-are-not-translated-in-stack-overflow-careers) via the excellent new Stack Exchange *highly sophisticated city name geo-localization engine*<sup>TM</sup> which you can find described in the answer to that question.

On the French [main careers page](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/), however London is still not translated in the Emplacements list and neither is the word Remote:

[image: Emplacements screenshot]

Note that Remote appears to be translated as télétravail on [this page](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/remote) so it may be that the translation from there can be reused for that word (if you check out the dropdown for Emplacement it's even present with an initial capital letter).

[image: Télétravail]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Fixed!</strike>

This bug has now been fixed! Look at the following screenshot!

[image]

Comment: lol: http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/39425!

Comment: I just made an edit which should significantly improve the quality of this post.